# How can this Dart arrow function have a statement in its body?

Tags: flutter, dart

If you see this Google I/O'19 presentation: https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I?t=498

at 8:18, in the `_onValueChanged`, there is

```
setState(()=>_value = value);
```

But on Dart official site, it says that only 'expression' can come after the fat arrow(=>):

> The => *expr* syntax is a shorthand for { return *expr*; }.

*(So actually it's the same as `setState((){return _value = value})`)*

I think the assignment `_value=value` is a statement, not an expression.

How can this possible?

Comment: I think it's just similar with `_value = value; return _value;`, just written in shorthand. `return` evaluates the statement first before returning. Sample `return 1 + 1;`.

Comment: @rickimaru As far as I know, in usual programming languages, `return` evaluates an 'expression', not a statement, doesn't it? `return 1+1;` is totally okay, but there can't be `return if(...){...}`(you can't return the if statement).

Comment: It is still the same for conditional statements though. The value is returned not really the `if else` statement. Sample, `int isEven(int n) => n % 2 == 0;`. This is the same as `return n % 2 == 0 ? true : false;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no contradiction.  Assignments are a type of expression.  That's how code like:

```dart
int x;
int y;
x = y = 42;
```

works: `x = y = 42` is a compound expression that's evaluated as `x = (y = 42)`.

Comment: Thanks! When you say *"Assignments are a type of expression."*, is it applied only in Dart, or is it language-agnostic? (in some languages, for example C or Kotlin, assignments are statements as far as I know.)

Comment: Many languages have it.  Some don't.  Case-by-case basis.

Comment: @starriet Assignments are expressions in C; again, that's how `x = y = 42` works.  Assignments are expressions in most languages that descend from C.  You perhaps are confusing assignments with *declarations* (e.g. `int x;`), which are statements (and sometimes declarations simultaneously initialize variables (e.g. `int x = 42;`)).